# leak-finder-for-javascript error during installation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

i get the following error during the installation of memory leak javascript from chrome

abrar@ubuntu:~/leakfinder$ gclient sync
Syncing projects:  33% ( 1/ 3) leak-finder
**____** running 'svn checkout http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/test/pyautolib /home/abrar/leakfinder/pyautolib --non-interactive --ignore-externals' in '/home/abrar/leakfinder'
svn: URL 'http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/test/pyautolib' doesn't exist
Syncing projects:  66% ( 2/ 3) pyautolib

### pyautolib (ERROR)

### [0:00:01] Started.

Error: Command svn checkout "same link as above" /home/abrar/leakfinder/pyautolib --non-interactive --ignore-externals returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/abrar/leakfinder
abrar@ubuntu:~/leakfinder$